# sql datetime convert to hql

Tags: sql, sql-server, hql

I am working on the following query:

```
SELECT att.AttendenceCD, convert(varchar, att.AttDate, 101) AttDate, att.EmployeeCD
FROM Attendance att
where att.EmployeeCD = 2234 and att.AttDate = '11/02/2011'
```

How can I convert this query into HQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this. i hope it will work

```
SELECT att.AttendenceCD, convert(varchar(10), att.AttDate, 101) AttDate, att.EmployeeCD
FROM Attendance att
where att.EmployeeCD = 2234 and att.AttDate = '11/02/2011'
```

other wise

```
SELECT att.AttendenceCD, cast(att.AttDate, datetime(101)) AttDate, att.EmployeeCD
FROM Attendance att
where att.EmployeeCD = 2234 and att.AttDate = '11/02/2011'
```